# Selecting multiple items in a listview

Tags: vb.net

This is my code:

```
Dim I As Integer
cn.BeginTrans()
cn.Execute("UPDATE tb_user_account SET st_time_per_day='" & TempTPD.Text &
        "' WHERE st_acc_number='" & ListViewAccounts.SelectedItems(I).Text & "'")
cn.CommitTrans()
```

Now what is does is update a selected item in a listview, and i'm using a context menu strip
what i noticed was, when i highlight two items it only updates 1. what i want to do is, to update items depending how many items i highlighted. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to iterate through all `SelectedItems` and execute update query for each :

```
cn.BeginTrans()
For Each selectedItem As ListViewItem In ListViewAccounts.SelectedItems
    cn.Execute("UPDATE tb_user_account SET st_time_per_day='" _ 
                & TempTPD.Text & _
                "' WHERE st_acc_number='" _
                & selectedItem.Text & "'")
Next
cn.CommitTrans()
```